# Нужно добавить листание слайдера на мобильной версий сайта в Next js (без использования Swiper, slick-slider и др)

Tags: slider, nextjs, swipe, touch-event

Я недавно начал работать с Next js и у меня возникла проблема при работе с событиями OnTouchStart,OnTouchMove и OnTouchEnd. Раньше реализовывал такое на React и на чистом js. Сейчас когда я хочу получить clientX(Координата нажатия) и deltaX(изменение координаты) в консоль выводится что clientX равен undefined и поэтому не получается узнать в какую сторону клиент листает. В итоге получилось что слайдер листается только в одну сторону, а clientX и deltaX равны undefined.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот вам слайдер https://snap.glitch.me/carousel.html без использования JS

Answer (score 0):

Я уже разобрался с этой проблемой, нужно было вместо event.clientX, писать event.touches[0].clientX.

Кому в будущем понадобится сделать свайп для слайда держите код

```
let xDown;
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1);
const length = slides.length;
const nextSlide = () => {
   setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
};

const prevSlide = () => {
   setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
};

if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
   return null;
}


const getClientX = (e) => {
   const firstTouch = e.targetTouches[0]
   xDown=firstTouch.clientX
}

const Swipe = (e) => {
   if ( !xDown ) {
      return;
}

let xUp=e.touches[0].clientX
let xDiff = xDown-xUp
if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
       nextSlide()
   } else {
       prevSlide()
   }
}
<div className={styles.slider_container}
   onTouchStartCapture={(e)=>getClientX(e)}
   onTouchMove={(e)=>Swipe(e)}
>
   {/*Тут содержание слайдера*/}
</div>
```